# Field 'Job.jobItem' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null... Job.jobItem doesn't exist

Tags: c#

It's almost like it can't forget about what was previously there, even after saving and restarting.

The first block of code is from my Models folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace ResumePortfolioSite.Models
{
    public class Job
    {
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This next block of code related to Jobs specifically is in my ViewModels folder

```
using ResumePortfolioSite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ResumePortfolioSite.ViewModels
{
    public class ResumeIndexViewModel
    {
        public List<Education> EducationItems { get; set; } = new List<Education>();
        public List<Job> JobItems { get; set; } = new List<Job>();
        public List<Skill> SkillItems { get; set; } = new List<Skill>();
    }
}
```

And this block, still related to jobs, is in my Services folder, using an interface within the same folder.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ResumePortfolioSite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ResumePortfolioSite.Services
{
    public class ResumeDbContext : DbContext, IResumeRepository
    {
        public ResumeDbContext(DbContextOptions<ResumeDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        DbSet<Education> Educations { get; set; }
        #region Education methods
        public List<Education> GetAllEducationEntries()
        {
            return Educations.ToList();
        }
        public bool AnyEducationItemsExist()
        {
            return Educations.Any();
        }
        public void AddEducationItem(Education educationItem)
        {
            Educations.Add(educationItem);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        public async Task<int> UpdateEducationItem(int id, Education education)
        {
            Entry(education).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                await SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EducationItemExists(id))
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return education.EducationId;
        }
        public async Task<Education> FindEducationItemAsync(int id)
        {
            return await Educations.FindAsync(id);
        }
        public void RemoveEducationItem(Education education)
        {
            Educations.Remove(education);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        private bool EducationItemExists(int id)
        {
            return Educations.Any(e => e.EducationId == id);
        }
        #endregion
        DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        #region Job Methods
        public List<Job> GetAllJobs()
        {
            return Jobs.ToList();
        }
        public bool AnyJobItemsExist()
        {
            return Jobs.Any();
        }
        public void AddJobItem(Job jobItem)
        {
            Jobs.Add(jobItem);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        public async Task<int> UpdateJobItem(int id, Job jobItem)
        {
            Entry(jobItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                await SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!JobItemExists(id))
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return (int)jobItem.JobId;
        }
        public async Task<Job> FindJobItemAsync(int id)
        {
            return await Jobs.FindAsync(id);
        }
        public void RemoveJobItem(Job jobItem)
        {
            Jobs.Remove(jobItem);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        private bool JobItemExists(int id)
        {
            return Jobs.Any(e => e.JobId == id);
        }
        #endregion
        DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
        #region Skill methods
        public List<Skill> GetAllSkills()
        {
            return Skills.ToList();
        }
        public bool AnySkillItemsExist()
        {
            return Skills.Any();
        }
        public void AddSkillItem(Skill skill)
        {
            Skills.Add(skill);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        public async Task<int> UpdateSkillItem(int id, Skill skill)
        {
            Entry(skill).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                await SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!SkillItemExists(id))
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return skill.SkillId;
        }
        public async Task<Skill> FindSkillItemAsync(int id)
        {
            return await Skills.FindAsync(id);
        }
        public void RemoveSkillItem(Skill skill)
        {
            Skills.Remove(skill);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        private bool SkillItemExists(int id)
        {
            return Skills.Any(e => e.SkillId == id);
        }
        public List<Skill> GetSkills()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Sorry, I am new to stack; Fixed the formatting...Thanks for looking!

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the link; I didn't see that information when I took the tour on stack.

Comment: @Progman, Thanks for the heads up; I changed the post to include the code that is flagging for the errors.